# Does prolonged use of VR headsets harm your vision?

Tags: vision, optometry

Virtual reality (VR) technology is starting to get to a point where it will become more common in the mainstream.  The technology involves placing screens very close to your eyes to create the vision. Id imagine a very close focus point that does not move which would possibly damage your vision over time.

Is this likely or is there some reason to think my assumption is wrong

Comment: Welcome to SE! Great question, I'm very interested by the potential answers!

Comment: Why do you think this would damage vision?

Comment: My guess is that focusing on at a short distance would have the eyes muscles / ligaments in an extreme position which over time could reduce the ability to move to other positions easily hence slowing focus or leaving things blurry.